# Reason behind Collections.sort(list) not working on (linked) hash sets?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, set, hashset

Why doesn't the `Collections.sort(list)` method of Java Collections work on hash sets or linked hash sets? What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null element.
From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html